# How to cancel a http request

Tags: java, android

This is my very first question on stack overflow. Normally i can find the answers on my own, but this time i can't find a decent answer anywhere. I'm also new at making apps for android, so sorry in advance for my noob'nes.

How do i cancel a http request in 'android java' after x miliseconds when a local IP adress is unavailable?
i'm requesting a html page using AsyncTask. The code of the class is given below.

What i have now is the following, a timer defined in the onPreExecute() , which sets the onCancel() to true after X miliseconds.
doInBackground() opens a stream etc. and after that it writes the stream to a string.

The problem is that when the local ip adress is unavailable then the url.openStream() function keeps running until java.net.ConnectException kicks in because of a timeOut. I don't know how to interupt this command using onCancel() (if this is even possible).

So how do i interupt the url.openStream command? or just terminate the AsyncTask thread in general?

```
    private class htmlToString extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    public htmlToString asyncObj;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        asyncObj = this;
        new CountDownTimer(connectionTimeout, connectionTimeout) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
            public void onFinish() {
                // stop async task if not in progress
                if (asyncObj.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                    asyncObj.cancel(true); // <- how can i cancel the doInBackground with this ?
                    Log.i("timer", "...still trying to connect...");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_string[button_state]);
            final InputStream url_inputstream = url.openStream(); // <- if the local ip adress is unavailable, this command keeps running until ETIMEDOUT kicks in
            InputStreamReader url_inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader( url_inputstream );
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( url_inputstreamreader );
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                page = page.concat(inputLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params){
        // some code
    }

}
```

Edit1 : This is done in Android Studio 1.5.1

Edit2 : I solved it on my own. I just shortend the timout set by java. I did this in the doInBackground() (code is given below). This also meant that i could completely scrap the timer inside the onPreExecute().

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_string[button_state]);
            URLConnection url_connection = url.openConnection();
            url_connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout); // timout is set here
            final InputStream url_inputstream = url_connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader url_inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader( url_inputstream );
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( url_inputstreamreader );
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                page = page.concat(inputLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can refer below code for cancel the request

```
 httpget.abort();
```

example:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;



public class ClientAbortMethod {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(<URL>);

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getURI());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

                // Call abort on the request object
                httpget.abort();
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i get the following errors: Cannot resolve symbol "ClosableHttpClient" , cannot resolve symbol "httpclients" , cannot resolve symbol "getUri" , cannot resolve symbol "getStatusLine" , cannot resolve symbol "abort" cannot resolve symbol "close"

Comment: this inteface is in package org.apache.http.client.methods

Comment: i imported the packages you stated, they give the following errors: Error:(23, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(24, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(25, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
Error:(26, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist

Comment: YOU GOT IT. Can you put a snippet reference as well, please?

Answer (score 2):

`httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();`

Comment: Where do i put this code? i also get the following error message: "Cannot resolve symbol 'httpclient' ". I've tried to put it into the "onfinish" function of the timer. I also tried to replace httpclient with the asyncObj. Plus i also tried to put it into main -> oncreate() and replaced the httpclient with the htmlToString class that i called, but then i get the error message: " can't resolve symbol 'getConnectionManager' "